# why nothing showing in ng-view?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I learning angular and I have problem. When I put script directly to code it works but when I am move js controllers to controllers.js it nothing to show. here is my code:

INDEX.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="pivoApp">
<head>
    <title>Pivovara Medvedgrad Kupci</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Početna</h1>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html#!/">Početak</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#!/registracija">Registracija</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div ng-view>

</div>  

</body>
```

templates/registracija.html

```
<div>
<h2>Registracija</h2>

<form  >
    Ime:<input type="text" ng-model="ime"/><br/>
    Prezime:<input type="text" ng-model="prezime"/><br/>
    Korisničko ime:<input type="text" ng-model="username"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="insertdata()"/></br>
</form>
```

templates/main.html

```
<div>{{message}}</div>
```

Controllers.js

```
'use strict';
// Controllers

    var pivoAppControllers = angular.module('pivoAppControllers', []);

    pivoAppControllers.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http',
        function MainCtrl($scope, $location, $http) {
            $scope.message = "Dobro došli u sustav za kontrolu skladišta u   pivovari Medvedgrad.";
    }])

pivoAppControllers.controller('regCtrl', function($scope,$http){
    $scope.insertdata = function(){
        $http.post("insert.php", {'ime':$scope.ime, 'prezime':$scope.prezime, 'username':$scope.username })
        .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
            console.log("Podaci uspiješno spremljeni");
            alert("Podaci za novog korisnika su uspiješno spremljeni. Novi korisnik se sada može prijaviti u aplikaciju sa navedenim podacima.");
        });
    }
});
```

app.js

```
'use strict';
// App Module


    var pivoApp = angular.module('pivoApp', [
      'ngRoute',
      'pivoAppControllers'
    ]);

    pivoApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
      function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        when('/registracija', {
          templateUrl: 'templates/registracija.html',
      controller: 'regCtrl'
        })
        ;



        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');
      }
]);
```

```css
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=pivoApp&p1=ReferenceError%3A%20when%20is%20not%20defined%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fjs%2Fapp.js%3A17%3A2%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A376)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A321)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A445%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A222)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20db%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A246)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A359)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Bc%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A163)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ge%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A484
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: yes this is error:   <-- angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=pivoApp&p1=Referenc…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A484)(…)(anonymous function)--> @jmona789

Comment: Is that the full url it is giving you for the error?  The error seems to be cut off in the middle of a word.  `Failed to instantiate module pivoApp due to:
Referenc`

Comment: [link]http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=pivoApp&p1=Referenc…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A484[link]

Comment: You missed a period before your second when please see my answer below, and remember to upvote and accept if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a period before one of your `whens` change your app.js to:

```
'use strict';
// App Module


    var pivoApp = angular.module('pivoApp', [
      'ngRoute',
      'pivoAppControllers'
    ]);

    pivoApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
      function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'main.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('templates/registracija', {
          templateUrl: 'registracija.html',
      controller: 'regCtrl'
        })
        ;
```

and it should work.
plunkr:https://plnkr.co/edit/6lUYQdVVClZVsW2wQ1SA?p=preview

Comment: Yea, I saw this answer should solve your issue^ Please let me know if you solve it

Comment: I am try and nothing.

Comment: I saw the missing dot too...If it isn't working @strava1 is it the same error? That dot should have fixed the error you posted

Comment: You changed your appjs to the example I gave? and still nothing?  Any other errors in the console?